# TF-IDF vector vs a vector of tokens

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, sequence-modeling

Some background:

I have data structured as the a TFIDF vector of shape `(15637, 31635)` and this is the input this vector into the `LSTM` layer. The longest word in my vocabulary is `305` words and each `TFIDF` vector has length `31635` because the total vocabulary in the corpus has these many words.

Each of the `15637 sentences` is a `TFIDF` vector of form `(31635, )`.

I am using the TFIDF instead of a pre-trained `embedding` layer.

`No_of_sentences = 15637`

`BATCH_SIZE = 64`

`steps_per_epoch  = 15637/64 = 244 (with remainder dropped)`

`vocab_inp_size = 31635. #These were tokens created by Keras tokenizer. and are the distinct words in the input corpus`

`vocab_tar_size = 4. #This is One-Hot encoding of target value`.

The code below first creates `tensor slices`, then batches the `tensor slices` and finally `enumerates` each `batch` to give a `tuple` of form: `(batch, (input_tensor, target_tensor))`.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_tfidfVector, target_tensor_train)).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True) # this is where batching happens

for (batch) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):`
   print (batch) #this will print the tuple: curent batch (batch 0) but also the input and the target tensor 

(0, (<tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 31635), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[0.        , 1.74502835, 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       ...,
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.74502835, 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.74502835, 3.35343652, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(64, 1), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[3],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [3],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [2],
       [3],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [1],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2],
       [3],
       [3],
       [1],
       [1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [1],
       [3],
       [2],
       [1],
       [3],
       [1],
       [3],
       [3],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]], dtype=int32)>))
```

Question:

I am not using a pre-trained embedding layer - but a TFIDF vector for each sentence. I am not removing stop words from the input - so TFIDF would downweight any words that are too frequent across the corpus.

Let's say I just use tokens created by the keras tokenizer (and not use a TFIDF vector for a sentence like explained above). In theory, is it a good choice..what do you think?

Note: 31635 is the size of the corpus (number of words in all sentences combined). So each sentence has the length of 31635, but it will be mostly sparse (padded) because the longest sentence in my input is about 300 words.

Comment: Hey, Utpal! Can you take a minute to describe what you've tried so far? What you expected the outcome to be and what it was? This is good background on the data preparation but it would be good to better understand where you are stuck. Are you using a Keras LSTM model?

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I will edit the question in some time with more detail.